# Facebook application oauth tokens expire?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Do facebook **application** access tokens expire? These tokens are used for administrative purposes.

I have had an access token work for more than two weeks, but I would like to see a reference to something official, which I cannot find.

EDIT: I was not clear enough in my initial question. I was referring to the administrative access tokens, which are not related to a specific facebook user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like administrative access token do not expire. I have had tokens active for several weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens expires when the facebook's user logs out it session, changes the application's permissions or after some time when application is no more used. The only case the access_token does not expire is when the extended permission offline_access has been granted.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions ("By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application.").